# I Can't Leave Lanayru Province In Twilight Princess?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

I need to get to Kakariko Village so I can escort the prince and get the Zora Armor. However, all exits from Lanayru Province are blocked off. Why can't I leave?

Additional Info: I am playing the Wii version

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: To advance I need to go to Kakariko to get the armor, but every bridge connecting Lanayru province to the other locations has been destroyed, and all the paths are blocked with gates that are too high for Epona to jump over.

Comment: Did you and Midna move the bridge that was outside the first dungeon? I haven't played in about 6 months.

Comment: the bridge that was in the forest? yeah i got that. im trying to get into the third dungeon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zora Prince Escort mission starts in Telma's Bar in Castle Town after you've removed the Twilight from Lanayru Province. You're trying to get the prince *to* Kakariko Village so that Renado can heal him.

After you make it to Kakariko safely,

> Queen Rutela's spirit will lead you to the spring behind the graveyard, where she'll give you the Zora Armor.

Comment: I was thinking Telma's bar was in Kakariko, thank you.